# Problem with image path [C#, WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, relative-path, wpf-4.0

I need use images in 2 .NET assemblies. One is WPF app {myApp.exe} and second is *.dll {myDll.dll}.  File are located in this file structure:

```
 **AppFolder** consist these files and one subfolder(avatars):

    -myApp.exe
    -myDll.dll
    -avatars {folder} consist:
          -manImages.jpg
          -womanImages.jpg
```

I try user uri in this format

```
new Uri(@"C:\Users\avatars\manImages.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

but this format does not work, images are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect

```
new Uri(@"avatars\manImages.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

to work?

You could also try:

```
new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\avatars\manImages.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that he wanted the new URL statement to work.  This is an answer to that question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hogan, in my questin is  mistake in @"C:\Users\avatars\manImages.jpg", it should be avatars\manImages. But it does not work. This    alternativ :            return new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\avatars\man.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);  work goods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the dll side you can write this:

```
string imgPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "avatars\\manImages.jpg");
```